# android ¿Como hacer para que el valor de una variable se pueda usar en toda mi aplicacion?

Tags: java, android

Buen día.

Tengo un login en mi app, pero necesito usar los datos de la session en toda la applicacion ¿Como lo deberia hacer?.
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pongo algunas posibilidades:

1.Pasar la información por los intents de las actividades

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MiActivity.class); 
       intent.putExtra("email", miEmail);

       startActivity(intent);

       //MiActivity
       email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
```

2.Usar SharedPreferences:

Guardar datos después del login:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("shared_login_data",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("email", "miemail@gmail.com");
editor.commit();
```

Recuperar datos al cambiar de actividad o fragment:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("shared_login_data",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = prefs.getString("email", ""); // prefs.getString("nombre del campo" , "valor por defecto")
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe la manera con [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=es-419) con las cuales puedes crear `key` y `values` y poder acceder a ellas en tus `Activity`

Cuando tu usuario inicie sesión puedes definir

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MisPreferences" ;
public static final String userName = "nombreUsuario";
public static final String userPassword = "passwordUsuario";

String username  = userName.getText().toString();
String password  = passwordUser.getText().toString();

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString(userName , username);
editor.putString(userPassword , password);
editor.commit();
//redireccionas por ejemplo a otra Activity
perfil = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second_main.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Y para acceder a los datos ya guardados en otra `Activity`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = getResources().getString("nombreUsuario");
```

> Un objeto SharedPreferences tiene asociado un archivo que contiene pares clave-valor y proporciona métodos simples para leer y escribir dichos pares. Cada archivo de SharedPreferences es administrado por el marco y puede ser privado o compartido.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta sioesi, tengo una duda, a nivel de seguridad, que tan viable es la solucion?

Comment: a nivel de seguridad te recomendaría que encriptaras los datos ,si son sensibles, antes de guardarlos en las SharedPreferences, ya que si un usuario es root puede acceder a los archivos de las SharedPreferences y leer el contenido

Comment: Yo pienso que la seguridad va en el dato, como dice @Joacer antes de guardar los datos como tal, encriptarlos, hacerles algo format o como el usuario este haciendo sus datos. Tambien sobre todo porque la mayoria de las veces las app se comunican con servidor, seria muy bueno encriptarlas antes de hacer peticiones externas. Yo deje la respuesta de la manera en que puede mantener un valor y acceder a el desde distintas partes de la app

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, una duda mas, SharedPreferences se guarda en el LocalStorage del dispositivo? es decir guarda datos, y aunque yo cierre la app los va a mantener, eso lo comprobe en mi app, pero quiero confirmar.

Comment: actualice mi respuesta, deje una cita de la documentacion en donde te explican que los shared preferences se guardan en un archivo privado o compartido, en este caso tus datos deben ser privados por eso `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`