# Comparar valores entre Actividades

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Quiero comparar el valor que toma la variable text2Qr con el valor que muestro en la siguiente imagen.[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K82kx.png)

Quiero comparar un valor de una actividad con otro valor de otra actividad, el valor que quiero comparar es el result.getContent() que es de un lector QR

Si alguien seria tan amable de ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho :)

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es pasar la información mediante intents. Te dejo más información. <br>
[Pasar la información por los intents de las actividades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33865)

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es pasar información mediante activities, te dejo aquí un ejemplo:

Realizas un Intent donde guardas los datos que necesitas (en este caso usamos un String)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), tuActividad.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Puedes acceder a esto desde la otra actividad:

```
String sessionId= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

¡Espero que te sirva!