# Asignar valor a variable global desde FirebaseFirestore

Tags: android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, variables-globales

Tengo una firebase conectada a una app, esta autentifica el correo después manda a MainActivity pero en ese momento quiero fijar el usuario se quede guardado en una variable global y esta se mantenga siempre hasta que no se cierre sesión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Esto te puede servir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/33860/29967).

Comment: Si, lo pensé, sin embargo no se asigna valor a la variable global que cree (ClassGoblal.setUsuarioactivo), cuando le puedo asignar el valor desde el firestore, usaré sharedpreferen e

Comment: Como dice @A.Cedano lo mejor que podes usar es sharedpreferences, no te olvides de que cuando salgas de tu actividad/fragment, en el onDestroy() limpies el sharedPreferences sino cuando vuelvas a entrar vas a seguir teniendo los valores guardados

Comment: No olvides agregar como texto el c[odigo ya que puede no ser visible para todos los miembros de la comunidad, saludos..